# When to use tabbing

Tags: tables, tabbing

When should I use the `tabbing` environment?  Whenever I want to line things up I reach for `tabular`, and I have this vague worry that I sometimes miss a simpler solution because I don't think in terms of `tabbing`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following might shed some light on when to use which:

- `tabular` creates an unbreakable block, while `tabbing` can break across the page boundary.
- `tabular` allows for creating specific alignments using the column specification, while `tabbing` assumes all tabs are `l`eft aligned.
- `tabular` can insert vertical and horizontal rules that span the width of the content, while it is very difficult to do with `tabbing`.
- `tabular` can make content wrap with the `p`aragraph column specification, while `tabbing` doesn't allow for this.
- `tabular` provides package support (through [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl), for example) for formatting.

Here is a small example showing the first couple of differences (perhaps most notable differences) between `tabular` and `tabbing` - alignment and page breaking:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=25\baselineskip,margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis 
sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, 
dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et 
risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor 
orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate 
id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan 
egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque 
maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ l c r p{10em} }
  \bfseries left & \bfseries center & \bfseries right & \bfseries paragraph \\
  first & second & third & fourth \\
  one & two & three & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  een & twee & drie & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  one & two & three & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  een & twee & drie & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{tabular}

\clearpage

\section{A section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis 
sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, 
dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et 
risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor 
orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate 
id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan 
egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque 
maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

\begin{tabbing}
  \bfseries left \quad \=\bfseries center \quad \=\bfseries right \quad \=\bfseries paragraph \kill
  \bfseries first \> \bfseries second \> \bfseries third \> \bfseries fourth \\
  one \> two \> three \> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  een \> twee \> drie \> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  one \> two \> three \> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  een \> twee \> drie \> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, seems that the primary advantage is natural page breaking.

Comment: @Mark and to get the best of both worlds, you might want to use the `longtable` package: It _defines a new environment, `longtable`, which has most of the features of the tabular environment, but produces tables which may be broken by TEX’s standard page-breaking algorithm._ [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable)

Comment: Yep, heard of it.  Never had tables that long though.